# Reactjs showing markdown in html

Tags: reactjs, markdown, jsx

I am using the library markdown.js to render my markdown. It returns it as a string. Now I am passing it to a react component by storing it in my state and then passing it down with `{<div>{this.state.markText}</div>` but I am facing the issue that it is being escaped. I do not want to use `dangersouslySetInnerHTML` because it is *dangerous* and I am getting everything from a user typing. How do I display the string I just got *safely* without using super complex compiling and stuff? I want to display this in my `render`:

```
<strong>Hello</strong>
```

*without danger or too much compiling*

Note: I am aware one other question exists but the answer only suggests custom  compiling the string. I do not want to do that.

Comment: React does escape html from strings. If you want react to render your string as html you have to use `dangersouslySetInnerHTML`.

Comment: But wont that be dangerous? Do I just need to escape other tags and use only the tags I want?

Comment: You should of course escape the untranspiled string the user has entered not allowing html or js code inside it. After escaping it you can pass it to your markdown transpiler. As long as you trust the transpiler to not do anything harmful this should be fine. But of course this way your user will not be able to use html in his markdown.

Comment: Ok thanks! I will just do that then